# Add a element to list

Tags: c++, list

I am trying to add an element to my List,but it fails.

The List always seems to have not changed when I try output it.

sample input : 1 3

sample output: 1 3

Can somebody tell me why and how to solve it?Thanks.

here is the Node and List

```cpp
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
    Node(const int& val = 0, Node* nextnode = nullptr)
        : value(val), next(nextnode) {}
};

class List {
public:
    List() : head(new Node) {}
    void CreateList(int n);
    void insert_to_end(int val);
    void transe_list() const {
        for (Node* i = head->next; i != nullptr; i = i->next) {
            cout << i->value << " ";
        }
    }
private:
    Node* head;
};

void List::CreateList(int n) {
    int value;
    Node* temp = head;
    while (--n >= 0) {
        cin >> value;
        Node* nextnode = new Node(value);
        temp->next = nextnode;
        temp = nextnode;
    }
}

void List::insert_to_end(int val) {
    Node* temp = head->next;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp = new Node(val);
}
```

and this is main()

```cpp
int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) 
{
    List intList;
    intList.CreateList(2);
    intList.insert_to_end(9);
    intList.transe_list();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `List::insert_to_end` you only change the local variable `temp`, which has no effect on the state of the list (and leaks memory). This should work:

```
void List::insert_to_end(int val) {
    Node* temp = head; // start with head

    while (temp->next != NULL) { // iterate until end, then temp points to the last node
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp->next = new Node(val); // append new node as follower to the currently last node
}
```

Keep in mind that you need to handle the special case when the list has not been initialized and `head` is `nullptr`, but that implementation is up to you.